# Using the LookAt() function in Unity

Tags: c#, function, unity-game-engine

So I have an assignment that I have to do for school where an enemy shoots at the player in a gun type game. I have read about the LookAt() function in the Unity tutorials and used it to my knowledge of it. However it doesn't seem to be working. The following code is what I have so far:

```
public class EnemyControl : MonoBehaviour {
private Rigidbody rb;
public GameObject Bullet_Emitter2;
public GameObject EnemyBullet;
public float speedOfBullet;
private int score;
public Text countText;
public Text winText;
private GameObject Temporart_Bullet_Handler2;
public Transform player;
public Transform enemy;

void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    score = 0;
}

private void Update()
{
    enemy.LookAt(player);
}
// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate () {
    int fire = Random.Range(0, 100);
    if(fire == 0 || fire == 1 || fire == 5)
    {
        Temporart_Bullet_Handler2 = Instantiate(EnemyBullet, Bullet_Emitter2.transform.position, Bullet_Emitter2.transform.rotation) as GameObject;

        Temporart_Bullet_Handler2.transform.Rotate(Vector3.right * 90);
        Rigidbody Temporary_Rigid_Body;
        Temporary_Rigid_Body = Temporart_Bullet_Handler2.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

        Temporary_Rigid_Body.AddForce(transform.up * speedOfBullet);

        Destroy(Temporart_Bullet_Handler2, 20.0f);
    }
}
```

}

The problem is my enemy now just looks at the ground instead of me and then just shoots downwards. Is there a way I can fix this? I have attached an image of what it looks like to a player playing the game?

[image]

Before putting in the LookAt() function my spaceman would just be stationary and fire bullets in a straight line but I need the AI to track the player instead of stationary. Is there another way to do this without using LookAt() or am I using this function wrong?

Thanks for the help in advance?

Comment: Are you sure your enemy's z-axis lines up with the direction you expect them to be facing? All `LookAt()` does is point the z-axis of the object at the specified point.

Answer (score 0):

---

**I would post this in comments but I can't yet because of low reputation**

---

As Serlite pointed out, `LookAt()` only faces the GameObject's trasnform.forward (which is desired to be (0, 0, 1) when the object is not rotated) towards the target passed as argument.

To 'fix' this simply add an empty GameObject to your Hirarchy and set your AI object as its child

```
Empty GameObject
 - AI GameObject (with your script)
```

Now you can set a global rotation for your object (Rotate the parent) in a way that the AI's forwards faces z+.